# FusionTableLayer Map and Sidebar

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

The vanilla code you get when creating a map from a Fusion Table looks like document below.  Can a sidebar be created from within that also or do I need to dump the javascript and start from scratch?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#map-canvas { width:500px; height:300px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var layerl0;
function initialize() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.79274320730208, -118.12398762656244),
zoom: 12,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
layerl0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
query: {
select: "col4",
from: "1bjD4dXHwKM8AYfEFFDQk8Q2RID18EAJi5pSl0wY"
},
map: map,
styleId: 2,
templateId: 2
});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you must start from scratch

Answer (score 0):

A sidebar can be added to that code, but it needs to query the table to populate the sidebar.  A couple of examples are below.  You might also be able to make it work by triggering a click event on the FusionTablesLayer.

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_AfricaMap_kml_sidebar.html)

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_Watershed_Stewards_Map_sidebar2.html)

Comment: Thank you for the examples but neither of them use the stock javascript framework.  I've done a fair amount of customization of the infowindow from within the FusionTable and I'm hoping to avoid starting from scratch in javascript.

Comment: You don't need to start from scratch.  You do need to understand how it all works though.  If you make your FusionTable accessible and downloadable (or at least one that is in the format that you are using, doesn't need to include real data), I might be able to put together a proof of concept (unless [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490535/fusion-table-query-zoom-on-a-marker-from-an-external-link) works).